# getting customer info from magento table structure

Tags: php, magento

I want to get rows for all customer details from magento tables.

Can anyone give me the query?

Tables are:

- customer_entity
- eav_attribute
- customer_entity_varchar

Comment: Can you post the schema of the tables so we have something to work with?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's possible to extract some data from Magento MySQL DB, but before executing a queries below notice following:

1) Magento is built to be configurable, so that you must not fetch data from MySQL, but you must use Magento Customer module (models, resource models) and Magento configuration data to retrieve customer data. Any straight query is not guaranteed to be compatible with different Magento versions and even installations of same version.

2) Magento EAV structure does not allow you to fetch all customer data in a nice form within one query, because table names are matched to attributes dynamically.

3) You cannot extract ALL customer data just by one query or even multiple queries. Because many informational objects are created within models and only model has the logic to gather all data within one customer object. I talk about shipping/billing addresses, store credit, reward points (for EE version) and so on.

However just to fetch all customers' varchar attributes you can use following code (not guaranteed to work due to mentioned above in 1):

```
SELECT ce.*, ea.attribute_code, cev.value
  FROM customer_entity AS ce 
  LEFT JOIN eav_attribute AS ea ON ce.entity_type_id = ea.entity_type_id AND ea.backend_type = 'varchar'
  LEFT JOIN customer_entity_varchar AS cev ON ce.entity_id = cev.entity_id AND ea.attribute_id = cev.attribute_id
```

Also it's possible to use such a query to extract all attributes for a customer

```
SELECT ce.*, ea.attribute_code, 
    CASE ea.backend_type 
       WHEN 'varchar' THEN ce_varchar.value
       WHEN 'int' THEN ce_int.value
       WHEN 'text' THEN ce_text.value
       WHEN 'decimal' THEN ce_decimal.value
       WHEN 'datetime' THEN ce_datetime.value
       ELSE NULL
    END AS value
  FROM customer_entity AS ce 
  LEFT JOIN eav_attribute AS ea ON ce.entity_type_id = ea.entity_type_id
  LEFT JOIN customer_entity_varchar AS ce_varchar ON ce.entity_id = ce_varchar.entity_id AND ea.attribute_id = ce_varchar.attribute_id AND ea.backend_type = 'varchar'
  LEFT JOIN customer_entity_int AS ce_int ON ce.entity_id = ce_int.entity_id AND ea.attribute_id = ce_int.attribute_id AND ea.backend_type = 'int'
  LEFT JOIN customer_entity_text AS ce_text ON ce.entity_id = ce_text.entity_id AND ea.attribute_id = ce_text.attribute_id AND ea.backend_type = 'text'
  LEFT JOIN customer_entity_decimal AS ce_decimal ON ce.entity_id = ce_decimal.entity_id AND ea.attribute_id = ce_decimal.attribute_id AND ea.backend_type = 'decimal'
  LEFT JOIN customer_entity_datetime AS ce_datetime ON ce.entity_id = ce_datetime.entity_id AND ea.attribute_id = ce_datetime.attribute_id AND ea.backend_type = 'datetime'
```

Answer (score 9):

Just to complement @Stefano´s response, i've made a big query, just to extract some other important details, like address and phone. Some of these details will only make sense on my database, but can help someone:

```
SELECT c.entity_id,c.email, 
            (
            SELECT fn.value
            FROM customer_entity_varchar fn
            WHERE c.entity_id = fn.entity_id AND 
             fn.attribute_id = 12) AS password_hash, 
             (
            SELECT fn.value
            FROM customer_entity_varchar fn
            WHERE c.entity_id = fn.entity_id AND
             fn.attribute_id = 5) AS name, 
             (
            SELECT fn.value
            FROM customer_entity_varchar fn
            WHERE c.entity_id = fn.entity_id AND 
             fn.attribute_id = 7) AS lastname,
             (
            SELECT fn.value
            FROM customer_entity_varchar fn
            WHERE c.entity_id = fn.entity_id AND 
             fn.attribute_id = 150) AS cpfcnpj, 
             (
            SELECT fn.value
            FROM customer_address_entity_varchar fn
            WHERE ca.entity_id = fn.entity_id AND 
             fn.attribute_id = 149) AS cpfcnpj2,
             (
            SELECT fn.value
            FROM customer_address_entity_varchar fn
            WHERE ca.entity_id = fn.entity_id AND 
             fn.attribute_id = 145) AS rg,
             (
            SELECT fn.value
            FROM customer_address_entity_varchar fn
            WHERE ca.entity_id = fn.entity_id AND 
             fn.attribute_id = 151) AS phone1,
             (
            SELECT fn.value
            FROM customer_address_entity_varchar fn
            WHERE ca.entity_id = fn.entity_id AND 
             fn.attribute_id = 31) AS phone2,
             (
            SELECT fn.value
            FROM customer_address_entity_varchar fn
            WHERE ca.entity_id = fn.entity_id AND 
             fn.attribute_id = 27) AS country,
             (
            SELECT fn.value
            FROM customer_address_entity_varchar fn
            WHERE ca.entity_id = fn.entity_id AND 
             fn.attribute_id = 28) AS state,
             (
            SELECT fn.value
            FROM customer_address_entity_varchar fn
            WHERE ca.entity_id = fn.entity_id AND 
             fn.attribute_id = 26) AS city,                 
             cat.value AS address,
             (
            SELECT fn.value
            FROM customer_address_entity_varchar fn
            WHERE ca.entity_id = fn.entity_id AND 
             fn.attribute_id = 30) AS cep
            FROM customer_entity AS c
            LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity AS ca ON c.entity_id = ca.parent_id
            LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_text AS cat ON cat.entity_id = ca.entity_id                

            GROUP BY entity_id
```

Comment: @PableKarzin this works for me exactly how I wanted thanks for that however can you please tell me how can I change this so that I can set a where condition for phone number as right now it provides the complete data?

Comment: Thanks. You want only the phone number. That's it?

Comment: I want to set a where clause so that I can get the user's data by passing a phone number in where clause so that instead of getting all customers I can get a specific customer on the basis of their phone number

Comment: Try this: Before the line `GROUP BY entity_id` write
`WHERE  phone1 = '1111-1111'` . I didn't test it but i think it could work

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I spent hours trying to get the same information by using the SOAP API but a request would take 5 minutes to complete. This is certainly better and arguably the best.

Answer (score 8):

This is a little query to extract the customer details from magento tables:

```
select c.*, 
  (select fn.value from customer_entity_varchar fn where c.entity_id = fn.entity_id and
    fn.attribute_id = 5) as Name, 
  (select fn.value from customer_entity_varchar fn where c.entity_id = fn.entity_id and 
    fn.attribute_id = 7) as Lastname
from customer_entity c
```

Answer (score 3):

I read what's above and I feel much better knowing that some people out there are trying to figure out the issue as mine.
Well, As you may know, you can't find the whole information about your clients in magento back-office. 
I wanted to have a very big table where I can see all of my clients (those who have an account= registred) ( and those who just registred to news letters newsletter_subscribers)

Since I don't really know how magento provides those information, I wrote som SQL code to extract data.

As It is said above you can't have all the information about clients in one query. Actually, you will need as much queries as the clients Attributes.
If the entity client has 45 attributes (name, lastname, middlename, email .....) 
then you will need 45 queries to extract them...
My question was HOW ???

The answer is VIEWS !!
Actually, I wrote Views to extract each attribute information. That means That I wrote 45 veiws, each view  selects an attribute

I don't know How it is done in your database, but, You may know that Each entity has a entity_type_id.
In my case, I'm interested in the customer_entity and the customer_address_entity.
the customer_entity has a entity_type_id = 1
the customer_address_entity has an entity_type_id = 2

Each entity has attributes. So, if you want to see what are the attributes available for the customer entity run the query :

`Select attribute_code, attribute_id, backend_type from eav_attribute where entity_type_id =1`
Same thing for address entity by replacing the 1 by 2.

The column attributes_id is very important because this will enable you to find your attributes by id the tables :
entity_customer_vachar, entity_customer_int, entity_customer_text, entity_customer_datetime
You'll maybe find out the the firstname attribute_id = 5  in this table as Joseph Mastey wrote in he's query...

The information are dispatched by type in the tables above.
When you run the query above, you will see that each attribute has a backendtype. that means that the informations you are looking for is one of the tables suffixed by its type.
For example, if you are looking for firstname which type is varchar, then you'll find it in customer_entity_varchar and so on.

If you are still reading, that may mean you understand what I'm talking about.
Other wise you need to look at the EAV model 
And the magento 1.3.2.4 database schema at 
http://inchoo.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/MAGENTO_v1.3.2.4-Database_Diagram.pdf

I can't post the whole solution because It's not ready yet, I'll put a zip file if that can help.

Meanwhile, If someone knows how the use magento objects wiht a php file to get to the data without editing the magento Core, that would be great!
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for actual SQL for this or some Magento code? The actual SQL is going to get messy, and probably won't ever look the way you want it to.

Since there's no "pivot" in MySQL, you can basically ignore `eav_attribute` in the actual query. You'll be looking at it to find the attribute IDs you want. Here's a trivial example of how to select this data:

```
select c.*, fn.value firstname
    from customer_entity c
    join customer_entity_varchar fn
        on c.entity_id = fn.entity_id and fn.attribute_id = 5
;
```

Keep adding those join clauses for every attribute, and you'll have your query. Basically, EAV is not optimized for this kind of access.

If you give a little more detail about what you are trying to do (or whether PHP code in Magento will work for your purposes), we may be able to help you further.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 2):

I was specifically attempting to export customers mobile phone numbers from my Magento store.

Firstly you can do this using Data profiles as it extends to the Customer data set.

In my case the data profiles function was not working for some reason and as I did not have time to work out why I went directly to MySQL to get at my data.

The following MySQL query will enable you to extract customers with UK mobile phone numbers. Note: you may need to work out which attribute_id the data you need is and update in the query accordingly.

```
attribute_id value
26 Country
19 First_Name
21 Surname
31 Telephone
```

QUERY:-

```
SELECT 
`firstname`.`value` as `First_Name`, 
`surname`.`value` as `Surname`, 
`telephone`.`value` as `Telephone`,
`customer_entity`.`created_at`,
`customer_entity`.`updated_at` 
FROM 
`customer_address_entity_varchar` as `country` 
INNER JOIN 
`customer_address_entity_varchar` as  `firstname` USING (`entity_id`) 
INNER JOIN 
`customer_address_entity_varchar` as  `surname` USING (`entity_id`) 
INNER JOIN 
`customer_address_entity_varchar` as  `telephone` USING (`entity_id`) 
INNER JOIN 
`customer_entity` USING (`entity_id`) 
WHERE 
`country`.`attribute_id` = 26 && 
`country`.`value`="GB" && 
`firstname`.`attribute_id` = 19  && 
`surname`.`attribute_id` = 21  && 
`telephone`.`attribute_id` = 31  && 
`telephone`.`value` LIKE "07%"  
GROUP BY `telephone`.`value` 
limit 0,10;
```

Note the limit and the where statement limiting the result to specific data, the group stops duplicate numbers as the actual data I want is the phone number. You could add INTO OUTFILE to export result set to CSV.

Hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT customer_address_entity_varchar.value, customer_entity.entity_id
FROM customer_address_entity_varchar

LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity 
ON customer_address_entity_varchar.entity_id = customer_address_entity.entity_id

LEFT JOIN customer_entity 
ON customer_address_entity.parent_id = customer_entity.entity_id

WHERE attribute_id =31
```

Answer (score 1):

Another sample sql code for getting attribute values. I used only int and varchar attributes, you can also add others.

```
select c.entity_id, c.email, 
    a.attribute_id, a.attribute_code, a.frontend_label, a.backend_type, a.frontend_input, 
    case a.backend_type 
        when 'int' then coalesce(o.value, cei.value)
        when 'varchar' then cev.value
    end as value
from customer_entity c
left join eav_attribute a on a.entity_type_id = c.entity_type_id
left join customer_entity_int cei on     a.backend_type = 'int'     and cei.attribute_id = a.attribute_id and cei.entity_id = c.entity_id and cei.entity_type_id = c.entity_type_id
left join customer_entity_varchar cev on a.backend_type = 'varchar' and cev.attribute_id = a.attribute_id and cev.entity_id = c.entity_id and cev.entity_type_id = c.entity_type_id
left join eav_attribute_option_value o on a.backend_type = 'int' and a.frontend_input = 'select' /* and o.store_id = c.store_id */ and o.option_id = cei.value
-- where c.entity_id = 17651
having value is not null
order by c.entity_id, a.attribute_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the great answer of Andrey Tserkus. And added a new WHERE clause. Now you **just need to replace the product SKU and you will get all customer recordsets, which bought the product**. Works fine for me in Magento 1.5.1

```
/* Just replace the value for i.sku in line 32, with the corresponding sku of the product you want to get the buyers from*/

SELECT
    `e`.*,
    `at_prefix`.`value` AS `prefix`,
    `at_firstname`.`value` AS `firstname`,
    `at_middlename`.`value` AS `middlename`,
    `at_lastname`.`value` AS `lastname`,
    `at_suffix`.`value` AS `suffix`,
    CONCAT(IF(at_prefix.value IS NOT NULL AND at_prefix.value != '',
        CONCAT(LTRIM(RTRIM(at_prefix.value)), ' '),
        ''),
        LTRIM(RTRIM(at_firstname.value)), ' ',
        IF(at_middlename.value IS NOT NULL AND at_middlename.value != '',
        CONCAT(LTRIM(RTRIM(at_middlename.value)), ' '),
        ''),
        LTRIM(RTRIM(at_lastname.value)),
        IF(at_suffix.value IS NOT NULL AND at_suffix.value != '',
        CONCAT(' ', LTRIM(RTRIM(at_suffix.value))),
        '')
    ) AS `name`
FROM `customer_entity` AS `e`
    LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_prefix` ON (`at_prefix`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_prefix`.`attribute_id` = '4')
    LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_firstname` ON (`at_firstname`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_firstname`.`attribute_id` = '5')
    LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_middlename` ON (`at_middlename`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_middlename`.`attribute_id` = '6')
    LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_lastname` ON (`at_lastname`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_lastname`.`attribute_id` = '7')
    LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_suffix` ON (`at_suffix`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_suffix`.`attribute_id` = '8')
WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '1') 
AND `e`.`entity_id` IN ( 
                SELECT DISTINCT o.customer_id FROM sales_flat_order_item i
                INNER JOIN sales_flat_order o ON o.entity_id = i.order_id
                WHERE o.customer_id IS NOT NULL
                AND i.sku = '10-10-10101-4'
            )
LIMIT 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be a more simpler query with no sub queries:

```
SELECT c.email, cv.value as fname, cv2.value as lname
FROM customer_entity c, customer_entity_varchar cv, customer_entity_varchar cv2
WHERE c.entity_id = $user_id
AND c.entity_id = cv.entity_id 
AND cv.attribute_id = 5
AND c.entity_id = cv2.entity_id 
AND cv2.attribute_id = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below is the code you can fetch the customer detail in Magento**

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$customerData = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer->getId())->getData();
Mage::log($customerData);}
```

**Its output will be in array like below:-**

```
 Array
(
    [entity_id] => 1
    [entity_type_id] => 1
    [attribute_set_id] => 0
    [website_id] => 1
    [email] => test@example.com
    [group_id] => 1
    [increment_id] => 000000001
    [store_id] => 1
    [created_at] => 2007-08-30 23:23:13
    [updated_at] => 2008-08-08 12:28:24
    [is_active] => 1
    [firstname] => Test
    [lastname] => User
    [password_hash] => 204948a40200e4238db2277d5:eg
    [prefix] => 
    [middlename] => 
    [suffix] => 
    [taxvat] => 
    [default_billing] => 274
    [default_shipping] => 274
)
```